# Looping through nested dictionary in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying out an implementation. Although I have figured the logic out, I am having issues representing it programatically. I need your help or guidance.

Below is the detailed explanation of my code and what i am trying to achieve, please pardon me as it would be a long read.

**What I want to achieve**

I want to create an endpoint - /order/tradeadvisor/{{producer_order_id}}, so that if the endpoint is hit, then it should first record the producer_order_id in a variable, then it should go to the Order model and loop through it fetching all order_id, user_id with the user_type=1.

After that it should, now produce a a single record where, the user caprice is equal to producer floorprice(where the producer is the logged in user) and then the user needed engery is equal to the producers surplus and then store this record in the Trade table.

**What i have done**

User.model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    dso = models.ForeignKey(to=Dso,related_name='dso',null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    roleId = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    customerId = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, default='')
    floorPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, max_length=255, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    capPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, max_length=255, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    tradeStrategy = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    username=models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_trading = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

User serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    energy_data = EnergyDataSerializer(read_only=True)
    dso = DsoSerializer(read_only = True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id',
                  'name',
                  'email',
                  'address',
                  'roleId',
                  'is_active',
                  'customerId', 
                  'dso',
                  'floorPrice',
                  'capPrice',
                  'tradeStrategy',
                  'username',
                  'is_verified',
                  'is_staff',
                  'is_trading',
                  'created_at',
                  'updated_at',
                  'energy_data', //this is a nested dictionary holding data of the energySurplus and energyNeeded 
                  )
        depth = 1
```

Trade Serializer:

```
class TradeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    consumer_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null=False, queryset=User.objects.all())
    producer_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null=False, queryset=User.objects.all())
    c_order_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null=False, queryset=Order.objects.all())
    p_order_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null=False, queryset=Order.objects.all())
    startTime = serializers.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        model = Trade
        fields = ('id',
                  'startTime',
                  'stopTime',
                  'price',
                  'c_order_id',
                  'p_order_id',
                  'consumer_id',
                  'producer_id',
                  'producer_location',
                  'consumer_location',
                  'energyQuantity',
              )
```

Order Serializer

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    trades = TradeSerializer(read_only=True, many= True)
    user_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(allow_null=False, queryset=User.objects.all())
    user_type = serializers.IntegerField()
    created_at = serializers.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('id',
                  'user_id',
                  'user_type',
                  'trades',
                  'created_at',
                )
        depth = 1
```

Views.py:

```
class TradeAdvisor(views.APIView):
    serializer_class = TradeSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)


    def get(self, request,  *args, **kwargs):
        user = self.request.user
        producer_order_id = self.kwargs['p_order_id']
        orders = Order.objects.filter(user_type=1)

        for order in orders:
            consumer = order.user_id
             
            if consumer['user_id']['is_trading']:
                if ((consumer['capPrice'] == user.floorPrice ) and (consumer['energy_data']['energyNeeded'] == user.energy_data['energySurplus'])):
                    date_time = datetime.datetime.now()
                    data ={
                            "startTime": date_time,
                            "stopTime": "",
                            "price": user.flooPrice,
                            "c_order_id": order.id,
                            "p_order_id": producer_order_id,
                            "consumer_id": consumer,
                            "producer_id": user,
                            "producer_location": user.address,
                            "consumer_location": consumer['address'],
                            "energyQuantity": user.energy_data['energySurplus']
                    }
                    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=data)
                    serializer.save()
                else:
                    return Response({'error': 'No active consumers'}, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            else:
                return Response({'error': 'No active consumers'}, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So this is what i have tried, i am pretty sure is wrong and also i do get an error
*'int'(consumer['user_id']['is_trading']) object is not subscriptable*

Answer (score 0):

Just use `consumer` as a `User` instance, i.e:

```
if consumer.is_trading:

# instead of
if consumer['user_id']['is_trading']
```

and later you want to check `Order`, not `User`. It's not about Django knowledge, everything here is almost pure pythonish.

PS. please don't set `ForeignKey` field with `_id`. It's very misleading for other developers. I've just lost 5 minutes because I didn't realise that.